# why mysql innodb could update data when alter table structure?

Tags: mysql, innodb

When I add a new column to a table, at the same time I update the table date before the alter table transaction finished, but the update data task succeeds, why?

Why does mysql innodb engine don't lock the table when altering table structure? If locking the table, why could I update the table data?

---

Conditions:

- My table data is too large, about `16000000` records.
- mysql version:`5.7.15`;

Comment: How many is `1600w`?

Comment: 1600w is 16000000,thx~

Comment: Enlighten me.  What language/locale/culture does that 'w' come from?

Comment: In china, 'w' means 10000.So 1w equals 10000~~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certain `ALTERs` do not require locking the table; some don't even modify any part of the data.  If you would like to show us the `ALTER` and provide the MySQL version number, we can be more specific.

Comment: the mysql version is 5.7.15.As you said, the alter table operation would not lock the table?could you offer some document link about the alter table operation?Because many developer think the operation that alter table would lock the table in internet.

Comment: @ismallboy - See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html and any links from that page.  Note, especially, references to `ALGORITHM=...`  That option usually defaults to the least invasive (most lock-free) option that is implemented.

Comment: In this documents, detail for the operation "alter table",thx~